# C++ sin() returns incorrect results

Tags: c++, trigonometry

i have this piece of code

```
bool Position::HasInLine(const Unit * const target, float distance, float width) const
{
    if (!HasInArc(M_PI, target) || !target->IsWithinDist3d(m_positionX, m_positionY, m_positionZ, distance))
        return false;
    width += target->GetObjectSize();
    float angle = GetRelativeAngle(target);
    float absSin = abs(sin(angle));
    return abs(sin(angle)) * GetExactDist2d(target->GetPositionX(), target->GetPositionY()) < width;
}
```

Problem i ran into is, that when i debug with gdb and try "p sin(angle)" it returns weird values - for angle 1.51423 it states that sin = 29 (so yes, i am putting in radians :-) ). More weird is, that when i try "p absSin" it always returns 0, and yes, i was on next line, so the "float absSin = abs(sin(angle))" line was already done.
Originaly there wasnt even included cmath, but the M_PI const was returning correct value, though i added #include  at the start of the .cpp file just to make sure, but nothing changed.

If it helps, im using linux kernel 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64
Any ideas?

Comment: when sin yields something >1 then something is *really* broken in your setup. Maybe someone has written an own sin function which hides the original one? you can use `nm` on you object and library files to search for offending files.

Answer (score 3):

The function `abs` (as defined in `cstdlib`) always takes an integer and returns an integer. When dealing with `double`s, you should be using `fabs` instead.

Another version of `abs` is defined in `cmath` (`#include <cmath>`). It is overloaded to accept (and return) both integers and doubles.

You may wish to double-check which version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't you be using fabs and not abs? abs takes ints and returns only ints

Comment: @Dragonkin in <stdlib.h> it is redefined and works only for ints.

Comment: Well, looks like you found the problem :-) sin(angle) in code without the "abs" returns correct values (although in gdb "p sin(angle)" still returns weird integers), compiling the final corrections right now :-)

Answer (score 1):

"for angle 1.51423 it states that sin = 29"

That's most probably an error of observation, not an error of the sin function.

The result should be in range -1 through +1.

Cheers & hth.,